# Appending path to svg and aligning them using snap

Tags: jquery, svg, snap.svg

I have an svg that when you click on it I'd like to take a path within the svg and append it to another svg. Problem is when the path gets appended they stack on top of each other.

Is there any way to have the paths line up from left to right and flush to each other.

Comment: Add some minimal markup and code so we can see what the problem is.

Comment: You could probably do something like compare their bounding boxes with getBBox(), and then move the element so its bounding box x1 is set to the others bounding box x2. Naturally you will have to do more checks to figure which sides were overlapping or whatever your requirement is.